# Redux: how to dispatch a unique object key (unique Id, instead of hard coded)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a Redux action called `makePost` which receives data that looks like this:

```
{
  comment: false,
  comments_text: "",
  like: 0,
  name: "test"
}
```

The action then pushes the data to Firebase Realtime Database. It then dispatches another action (called `post`) to update the current React state with the data and includes a unique response id (`id: response.key`). It looks like this:

```
export const makePost = (postObject) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const uid = getState().userId;
        database
            .ref(`users/${uid}/posts`)
            .push(postObject)
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch(
                    post({
                        key: uid,
                        id: response.key,
                        ...postObject,
                    })
                )
            })
    }
}
```

The `post` dispatch action looks like this:

```
export const post = (post) => {
    return {
        type: "POST",
        payload: {
            key: post.key,
            handle: "PLACEHOLDER",
            posts: {
                postKey: {
                    name: post.name,
                    like: post.like,
                    comment: false,
                    comments_text: []
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is regarding the `id: response.key`. When I dispatch `post`, I want `postKey` (object key) to be the unique response id (`id: response.key`), not hard coded as `postKey`. Is there a way to dynamically do this? I tried writing  it as  `post.id` but this doesn't work.

For  reference, the `POST` reducer looks like this:

```
const postsReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case POST:
            return [...state, action.payload];
```

This is what my React state looks like currently, notice the previous data (object 1) has the unique response Ids, but the latest post (object 2) is hard coded as `postKey`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) on the object that `post` is returning.

> The object initializer syntax also supports computed property names that allows you to put an expression in brackets `[]`, that will be computed and used as the property name.
>
> ```
> let some_key = 'abc';
> let obj = {
>   [some_key]: 123
> };
> // obj = { abc: 123 }
> ```

So in your case, use `[post.id]` as this computed property:

```js
export const post = (post) => {
  return {
    type: "POST",
    payload: {
      key: post.key,
      handle: "PLACEHOLDER",
      posts: {
        // Assumes that `post.id` exists
        [post.id]: {
          name: post.name,
          like: post.like,
          comment: false,
          comments_text: [],
        },
      },
    },
  };
};
```